# Integrating a form in React WordPress Theme with Custom Contact Forms and the WP REST API

Tags: wordpress, forms, rest, reactjs

I have built a fully working WordPress theme as a SPA using React/Redux and the WP REST API, but not I need to tackle forms, and have found that [Custom Contact Forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-contact-forms/) is compatible with the WP REST API, but I can't work out where to start - am I missing something completely obvious?

I have added a form in the admin area, but now I can't see any endpoints in the API to use to post form data to. Does anyone have any experience with this and can point me in the right direction?

Thank you :)

Answer (score -3):

after some serious struggles i got it working.

so you just need to add the form to the page content as usual inside wordpress admin. see https://github.com/tlovett1/custom-contact-forms#usage

The trick to getting the form to post successfully is adding the following header to all requests you make to the `WP-API`, including the `GET` requests. (but most importantly the header should be there when requesting a page with a form generated by CCF)

`'X-WP-Nonce': WP_API_Settings.nonce`

where `WP_API_Settings` is added to the global scope by wp-api

it seems the plugin, CCF, is adding a nonce token to the form based on the request so without that header it doesn't know how to post the form correctly/successfully.

### Summary:

- Add form to your page content (inside cms admin)
- add `X-WP-Nonce` header to your requests
- Make request for page or post (html will be in `content.rendered`)
- `Custom Contact Forms` will generate a form with the proper nonce metadata/token
- Fill out your form and hit submit

**Hope this helps**

see this issue on how i resolved it fully
https://github.com/tlovett1/custom-contact-forms/issues/285#issuecomment-277035363

Comment: In order to get the WP_API_SETTINGS object, you need to be logged in to the site. This object is really intended to be used in the WordPress cms UI. However, the question is seeking to solve the problem of posting form data from the front-end of the website through WordPress and into the database via the WP Rest API.